# Proper manipulation of Batch dimension while passing inputs in Keras

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm

My keras input is of the shape (83194,34,30), but to pass in the model, I only need (34,30) [83194 is the no. of examples]. What changes can I make? 1. In Data shape or 2. In type of Input given to keras?

Error Received: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (83194, 34, 30)

Code:

```
n_units = 50
src_vocab = tar_vocab = 30
src_timesteps = a
tar_timesteps = b
_input_ = Input(shape=[src_timesteps], dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim = src_vocab, output_dim = n_units, input_length=src_timesteps, mask_zero=False)(_input_)
layer_1 = LSTM(n_units)(embedding)
repeat = RepeatVector(b)(layer_1)
layer_2 = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True)(repeat)
final = TimeDistributed(Dense(tar_vocab, activation='softmax'))(layer_2)
model = Model(inputs = _input_, output= final)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
print(model.summary())

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
filename = 'model.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
model.fit(train_, test_, epochs=30, callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose=2)
```

train_ is of shape (83194, 34, 30), test_ is of shape (83194, 79, 30).

Comment: What does `a` for?

Comment: a = 34 (src_timesteps), b= 30 (tar_timesteps)

Comment: Thank you, but I asked for the purpose of these variable e.g. number of sample or length of sequence etc.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mention the task. Apparently, I am trying to make the Neural Network to spell. So, src_timesteps represents the Max-length of spelling input, and tar_timesteps represents the Max-length of spelling output.

Comment: your train and test should have the same shape. Why one is (34,30) and the other (79,30)? Your loss is 'categorical_crossentropy', what is your target data (y) shape?